# Multiple social clients in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

We have the following scenario: A multitenant application that can use more than one Facebook application to login. Based on the tenant the application must use either one or the other login provider.

In .NET Core 1.1 we were able to set the AuthenticationScheme attribute when registering the client:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions {
     AuthenticationScheme="FacebookScheme1"
}
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions {
     AuthenticationScheme="FacebookScheme2"
}
```

However, in .NET Core 2.0 the AuthenticationScheme attribute is missing, and I am now getting an error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Facebook'`

How can I work around this? Is there an equivalent to the AuthenticationScheme attribute?

Comment: Show your 2.0 code. The parameter still exists, just not on options.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Any help would be much appreciated.